# React custom hook is not updating from first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a custom hook to fetch data with events handlers, when I using it on click event  the hook makes the request on the second click

**useFetch.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeRequest } from '../utils';

const useFetch = (query = {}) => {
  const [request, setRequest] = useState({ ...query });

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    response: null,
    isError: null,
    isLoading: request.isLoading,
  });

  const fetchData = async () => {
    if (!request.url) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      const res = await makeRequest(
        request.url,
        request.method || 'get',
        request.body || null,
      );
      setData({
        response: res,
        isLoading: false,
        error: null,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setData({
        response: null,
        error,
        isLoading: false,
      });
    }
  };
  const onEvent = (req) => {
    if (req) {
      setRequest({ ...req });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => fetchData(), [request]);

  return { ...data, onEvent };
};

export default useFetch;
```

**Component File**

```
const { isLoading, isError, response, onEvent } = useFetch();

  const ClickMe = () => {
    onEvent({
      url: 'v1/profile/login',
      method: 'post',
      body: {
        username: 'eee@ddd.com',
        password: '2342332',
      },
    });
    console.log('response', response);
  };
return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => ClickMe()} type="button">
       
        Click Me
      </button>
    )
```

the log inside the ClickMe function is null in the first click but in the second click it returns the value

Answer (score 1):

Because `fetchData` is asynchronous function you cannot know when `resposne` will be set, that's why you cannot access it like normal sync code

in your app code you could observe `response` change to console it like

```js
useEffect(() => { console.log(response) }, [ response ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of console.log, the response is not fetched. Since when ever `response` changes, the component re-renders, you can try like below to see the updated values of `isLoading` and `response`.

```
return (
  <>
    {isLoading && <div> Loading... </div>}
    {`Resonse is ${JSON.stringify(response)}`}
    <button onClick={() => ClickMe()} type="button">
      Click Me
    </button>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, it's an asynchronous operation. If you want to use the response as soon as you called onEvent, you can do something along these lines using a promise :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeRequest } from '../utils';

const useFetch = (query = {}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (query) {
      fetchData(query)
    }
  }, []) // if query is provided, run query

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    response: null,
    isError: null,
    isLoading: true
  });
  
  const fetchData = async (query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!query.url) {
        reject('url needed')
      }
      makeRequest(query).then(res => {
        setData({
          response: res,
          isLoading: false,
          error: null
        })
        resolve(res)
      ).catch(error => {
          setData({
            response: null,
            error,
            isLoading: false
          });
          reject(error)
        });
      })
    })
  };

  // provide fetchData directly for lazy calls
  return { ...data, fetchData };
};

export default useFetch;
```

And then call it like so :

```
const { response, fetchData } = useFetch()

fetchData({
      url: 'v1/profile/login',
      method: 'post',
      body: {
        username: 'eee@ddd.com',
        password: '2342332',
      },
    }).then(res => ...);
```